# PHP session seems to work only after being called twice

Tags: php, session

I am quite confused and would appreciate some help. I have an index.php which starts a session at its very beginning (session_start();). From the browser, I see that a cookie PHPSESSID is created with the id of the session.

However, in the folder /var/lib/php/sessions (the session.save_path), nothing is put.

If I declare any session variables in index.php they are not passed over to other php scripts with session_start() (not even with session_id(the-whatever-PHPSESSID); session_start();).

However, if I call session_start() again, I get the session functioning as I thought it ought (and in the session.save_path I can find a reference to the session id created).

It is quite confusing to me and, perhaps, given by befuddlement, I might not be explaining what happens well. Please let me know if you require any more info!

Here is what I have:

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['sessionid'] = session_id();
$sessionid = "'".$_SESSION['sessionid']."'";
$_SESSION['maxQueries'] = 1883; //11*171 + 2
$_SESSION['cCount'] = 0;
$_SESSION['queries'] = 0;
?>
```

There is a form there (index.php) which has a captcha key created by a php file ([captcha code by Simon Jarvis](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10372770-RESOLVED-CAPTCHA-problems)) which also starts with session_start(). The captcha is generated like this:

(index.php)

```
<div class="field">
<input type="checkbox" id="human" name="human" onclick="captcha();"/>
<label for="human" class="humancb">I am human</label>
</div>
<div id = "captcha"></div>
```

(javascript)

```
if(document.getElementById("human").checked){
document.getElementById("captcha").innerHTML = "<img src='./assets
/php/captcha_code_file.php?rand="+ Math.random() +"' id='captchaimg' >
</img>";}
```

When I load index.php I see a PHPSESSID - nothing in /var/lib/php/sessions. When I click on the captcha checkbox (and the captcha_code_file.php is invoked) I get the session to work. What am I doing wrong? What am I so terribly missing?

Thank you!

Edit1: I think I managed to pinpoint the issue. As @Hans indicated, the culprit was the $sessionid variable. I was using it to pass it as input to a javascript function when the form was being submitted. Then, I was using the javascript var 'sessionid' in a xhr post request to a php page. All php pages had session_start() in the beginning and their session_id was also passed through javascript. In retrospect, I am not at all sure I can provide an argument as to why I did that, but, anyway, when I omitted that part and the javascript was sending in the xhr post all variables unrelated to the session, the issue seemed to go away. Again, I am not sure I phrase this well and I guess I should start slapping myself on the face a couple of times :D...

Edit2: I would have liked if I could choose BOTH answers as very helpful. This would have reflected the truth. However, Hans, please understand that even though you were closer in a sense (showed the culprit here), it all happened for a completely - or so I think - different reason. That is why I choose Walther's answer. If I could, I would have chosen both.

Thank you both so much for helping!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation:

> Sessions follow a simple workflow. When a session is started, PHP will
>   either retrieve an existing session using the ID passed (usually from
>   a session cookie) or if no session is passed it will create a new
>   session. PHP will populate the $_SESSION superglobal with any session
>   data after the session has started. When PHP shuts down, it will
>   automatically take the contents of the $_SESSION superglobal,
>   serialize it, and send it for storage using the session save handler.

=> saving to a file happens between requests when it's finished executing the current script, not on first session_start call.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Thank you very much @walther! However, could you explain to me why the session variables I declare in index.php are not passed over to other scripts?

Comment: @moijoune, based on your description, no. Sessions work for me without any problem, so it must be some minor problem with your server settings or with your code. Sometimes checking correct spelling of the variables can solve hour-long headaches. Can you post a minimal executable code that shows clearly your issue so we can reproduce it?

Comment: hi! Unfortunately, the process of minimizing the code is really lengthy and, in the end, I could end up wasting your time (no errors in the minimal version). I need to check, as you suggested, the full version for errors. I believe that I have done something wrong somewhere but don't know where. I'll post an update. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

$sessionid = $_SESSION['sessionid']; is the correct statement not

$sessionid = "'".$_SESSION['sessionid']."'";

Try this adjustment and see what happens

Comment: Thank you very much @Hans! That is used for something else, but I definitely take your point.